# time is not getting updated on page. Any ideas?

Tags: javascript

I want to show start time and also show the current time. For some reason its not working.

Here is the html

```
<body >
    <label>App Started At: </label><div id="starttime" />
    <label >Current Time: </label><div id="nowtime" />
</body>
```

and java script

```
var appStartTime = getCurrentTime();
updatetimes();
function updatetimes() {
        var nowStr = getCurrentTime();
        document.getElementById("starttime").innerHTML = appStartTime;
        document.getElementById("nowtime").innerHTML = nowStr;
        setTimeout(updatetimes, 5000);
    }
    function getCurrentTime() {
        var now = new Date()
        return now.getMonth() + "/" + now.getDate() + "/" + now.getFullYear() + " - " + now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" + now.getSeconds();
    }
```

Code is available at https://jsfiddle.net/nh6mun7L/
Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a self closing DIV.

E.g., dont do this:

```
<div />
```

Do this:

```
<div></div>
```

See: 
https://jsfiddle.net/nh6mun7L/1/

Comment: you are a genius sir